# Procedure or function 'UserManagement' expects parameter '@CallType', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CallcenterConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

cmd.Parameters.Add("@CallType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlCalltype.SelectedValue.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Format", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlFormat.SelectedValue.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@disposition", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlDisp.SelectedValue.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@SubDisposition", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlSubdisp.SelectedValue.ToString();
cmd = new SqlCommand("UserManagement", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

da.SelectCommand = cmd;
da.Fill(dt);
gvDetails.DataSource = dt;
gvDetails.DataBind();
gvDetails.Visible = true;
```

Comment: You're initializing another instance of `SqlCommand` for second time with `cmd = new SqlCommand("UserManagement", con);`, hence existing parameters were erased. Use `cmd.CommandText = "UserManagement"` instead (I'll write an answer to fix this in few minutes if necessary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line assigned new instance of `SqlCommand` to `cmd` for second time instead of using existing `SqlCommand` which contains declared parameters, therefore removing all parameters already declared above:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("UserManagement", con);
```

The correct way to manage `SqlCommand` with parameterized stored procedure should be like this, with `using` statement to manage system resources during execution (better to use `try...catch...finally` block in case you want to handle `SqlException`):

```
String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CallcenterConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
var dt = new DataTable();

using (var con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
{
    con.Open();
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("UserManagement", con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CallType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlCalltype.SelectedValue.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Format", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlFormat.SelectedValue.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@disposition", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlDisp.SelectedValue.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SubDisposition", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlSubdisp.SelectedValue.ToString();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        // using SqlDataAdapter
        using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter)
        {
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(dt);
        }

        // using DataTable.Load directly
        // dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    }
    con.Close();
}

// other stuff
```

NB: In short you can replace the second assignment of `cmd` in question using `cmd.CommandText = "UserManagement";`, hence it just supplying stored procedure name instead assigning another instance of `SqlCommand`. Also instead of `ExecuteNonQuery()` try using `ExecuteReader()` with `DataTable.Load()` method.

Comment: thanks.....it worked

Answer (score 3):

Your code is a big mess. To me it looks like you've just used copy and paste from a bunch of other places and don't quite really understand what's going on in there.

It should be something like this:

```
String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CallcenterConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using(var con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
{
    using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("UserManagement", con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CallType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlCalltype.SelectedValue.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Format", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlFormat.SelectedValue.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@disposition", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlDisp.SelectedValue.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SubDisposition", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlSubdisp.SelectedValue.ToString();
        using(var da = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
    }
}
gvDetails.DataSource = dt;
gvDetails.DataBind();
gvDetails.Visible = true;
```